# how can i get minimize and restore functionality on lightbox ..?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

like close button i want minimize functionality over light box so when it is minimized it comes to the bottom of the window showing only title and minimize button converted into restore button so when i press it ,that light box will appear and if any another lightbox is open they will get minimized.so i want only one lightbox to be opend.i tried i dn't hav any idea how i will do this if u can add some magic code to [this is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketul/RuGAy/1/) please look at it.
thank you

Comment: Hi there. You seem new to StackOverflow, so i thought I should say... generally we put our code into the question itself, don't just point to it on another site. For two reasons: 1) it's annoying for people trying to help you to have to go somewhere else to see it 2) that fiddle will disappear someday... but your Question will stick around for a long while - and if somebody else has the same problem as you and googles and finds your question, they'll want to see the code to be sure it's the same problem as them... so please put the code into the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this

```
 $('.lightbox').click(function() {
    var thisBox = $(this).attr("name");
            //console.log(thisBox);
    $('.backdrop,.' + thisBox).animate({
        'opacity': '.50'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.box').animate({
        'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop,.' + thisBox).css('display', 'block');
});
```

just comment console.log(thisBox)

Comment: without this edit,lightbox doesnt work,and then you can think about minimization

Comment: can u complete the functionality what i want..??

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could do this.